# How can I center this formula?

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[chapter]{algorithm}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} 
\begin{document}
\begin{spacing}{1.2}
\tableofcontents
\backmatter 
{\listoffigures  \listoftables \listofalgorithms} \end{spacing}
\include{Chapter1}
\include{Chapter2}
\end{document}
```

In chapter 1, I have:

```
\textbf{
\center{
\[
 %\frac{ax^2+bx+c}{\sin^2y+\cos^2z} \qquad 
\text{F-mesure}=\frac{\text{2 * (Précision * Rappel)}}{\text{(Précision + Rappel)}}
\]
}}
```

The result is here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/glHsN.jpg
How can I center this formula? (i'd like it exactly in the middle)

Comment: First of all please provide a working example. `spacing` is not known to basic latex. Second, you do not need an extra file, please put the sample code into the main example. Third, `center` is an environment. Forth don't attempt to boldify large pieces of text using a macro, use the `bfseries` environment. Fifth, `\text` needs `amsmath` or at least `amstext`. Sixth, it *is* already centered, even without the `center` env, so what exactly are you asking for?

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer :) No, with or without the center env, it is not centered (i'd like it in the middle of the page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works just fine, so what exactly is it you are asking for

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{bfseries}
  \[
  % \frac{ax^2+bx+c}{\sin^2y+\cos^2z} \qquad
  \text{F-mesure}=\frac{\text{2 * (Précision *
      Rappel)}}{\text{(Précision + Rappel)}}
  \]
\end{bfseries}

\end{document}
```

Here is a full example with text

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book} 
%\usepackage[showframe=true]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum*[1]
\begin{bfseries}
  \[
  \text{F-mesure}=\frac{\text{2 * (Précision *
      Rappel)}}{\text{(Précision + Rappel)}}
  \]
\end{bfseries}%
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

And an image

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer :) With Your Code the formula is not centered ... (i'd like it in the middle of the page)

Comment: Well, it *is* centered, so please explain what you mean by *centered*, are you talking about *centered vertically*?

Comment: http://imgur.com/AK2A0C5   (i'd like it exactly in the middle)

Comment: In that case would you please update your original MWE, there is stuff you are not telling us.

Comment: i have written "How can I center this formula?" and publish all my code

Comment: No you have not, that example does not compile!

Comment: with your code http://imgur.com/fSop04P

Comment: That is not an exact copy of my code, the distance between lines are too high. Also where exactly are you compiling this? You seem to be using an old version of `lipsum` (that is causing the `*[1]`). Are you just copying and pasting this into something else? Please don't, run my code as it is, do *not* change or add anything. WHat do you get then.

Comment: @researcher -- the formula *is* centered -- i measured it with a point-scale ruler.  it only appears to not be centered since the right-hand side is "heavier" than the left.  presumably you are talking about centering it horizontally, not vertically.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, the ops version of my code is clearly not centered, så something else is at play here

Comment: @daleif -- right.  (hadn't looked at that, only your code -- which looks just slightly off-center for the reason i mentioned.)  there's some *other* code that's not been shown.

Comment: It kinda look like the fleqn option